# How can I make a pannable, zoomable View like the one on Apple Maps?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to make a View that I can zoom in and out of and pan in all directions, much like the one on Maps by Apple.

I've tried using ScrollView([.vertical, .horizontal]) for the panning, and some code to make the zooming sort-of work (in the code below). During testing, the panning won't work when zoomed in and even the zooming isn't very well made.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct PanAndZoom: View {
    @State var currentZoom: Double = 0
    @State var finalZoom: Double = 0
    var zoom: Double {
        max(min(currentZoom + finalZoom + 1, 5), 0.1)
    }
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
            Group {
                Image("sampleImage")
            }
            .scaleEffect(zoom)
        }
        .gesture(
            MagnificationGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    currentZoom = value * 0.5 - 1
                }
                .onEnded { _ in
                    finalZoom += currentZoom
                    currentZoom = 0
                }
        )
    }
}

struct PanAndZoom_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PanAndZoom()
    }
}
```

If anyone could tell me how to achieve anything here or even just guide me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated! - I'm a bit of a newbie to SwiftUI!

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIkit widgets using uiViewRepresentable. i am attaching some code that might help you out.

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ImageModifier: ViewModifier {
    private var contentSize: CGSize
    private var min: CGFloat = 1.0
    private var max: CGFloat = 3.0
    @State var currentScale: CGFloat = 1.0

    init(contentSize: CGSize) {
        self.contentSize = contentSize
    }
    
    var doubleTapGesture: some Gesture {
        TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded {
            if currentScale <= min { currentScale = max } else
            if currentScale >= max { currentScale = min } else {
                currentScale = ((max - min) * 0.5 + min) < currentScale ? max : min
            }
        }
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
            content
                .frame(width: contentSize.width * currentScale, height: contentSize.height * currentScale, alignment: .center)
                .modifier(PinchToZoom(minScale: min, maxScale: max, scale: $currentScale))
        }
        .gesture(doubleTapGesture)
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: currentScale)
    }
}

class PinchZoomView: UIView {
    let minScale: CGFloat
    let maxScale: CGFloat
    var isPinching: Bool = false
    var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
    let scaleChange: (CGFloat) -> Void
    
    init(minScale: CGFloat,
           maxScale: CGFloat,
         currentScale: CGFloat,
         scaleChange: @escaping (CGFloat) -> Void) {
        self.minScale = minScale
        self.maxScale = maxScale
        self.scale = currentScale
        self.scaleChange = scaleChange
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pinch(gesture:)))
        pinchGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
    
    @objc private func pinch(gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            isPinching = true
            
        case .changed, .ended:
            if gesture.scale <= minScale {
                scale = minScale
            } else if gesture.scale >= maxScale {
                scale = maxScale
            } else {
                scale = gesture.scale
            }
            scaleChange(scale)
        case .cancelled, .failed:
            isPinching = false
            scale = 1.0
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

struct PinchZoom: UIViewRepresentable {
    let minScale: CGFloat
    let maxScale: CGFloat
    @Binding var scale: CGFloat
    @Binding var isPinching: Bool
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PinchZoomView {
        let pinchZoomView = PinchZoomView(minScale: minScale, maxScale: maxScale, currentScale: scale, scaleChange: { scale = $0 })
        return pinchZoomView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ pageControl: PinchZoomView, context: Context) { }
}

struct PinchToZoom: ViewModifier {
    let minScale: CGFloat
    let maxScale: CGFloat
    @Binding var scale: CGFloat
    @State var anchor: UnitPoint = .center
    @State var isPinching: Bool = false
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .scaleEffect(scale, anchor: anchor)
            .animation(.spring(), value: isPinching)
            .overlay(PinchZoom(minScale: minScale, maxScale: maxScale, scale: $scale, isPinching: $isPinching))
    }
}
```

after that you just need to call this code like this

```
import SwiftUI

struct yourView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geoMetryProxy in
            Image("yourImage")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: geoMetryProxy.size.width, height: geoMetryProxy.size.height)
                .scaledToFit()
                .clipShape(Rectangle())
                .modifier(ImageModifier(contentSize: CGSize(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height)))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really know how any of this works. I think I might just save this project for later or if Apple makes a way to do this easier. Thanks a lot though! 

Comment: swiftui provide you a wide range of customization. so i don't think so that it's gonna be easier any sooner. i can guide you through if you are interested.